# Re-Parse response from command line

Tags: c#, process, console-application

Im encoding a video using a command line app. The app returns a line which says:

% complete : 34%

This is updated as the media encodes. Is there a way using the process class to keep checking the standard output and passing it back to the main execution script? I have a class that starts the process and then writes the standard output to stringbuilder but I want to know how to keep checking it. This is the curent code...

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> StartProcess(string exePathArg, string argumentsArg, int timeToWaitForProcessToExit)
    {
        //the dictionary with the
        Dictionary<string, string> retDirects = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = exePathArg;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsArg;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            try
            {

                p.Start();

                p.WaitForExit(timeToWaitForProcessToExit);

                int exitCode;
                try
                {
                    exitCode = p.ExitCode;

                    StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;
                    StreamReader standardError = p.StandardError;

                    retDirects.Add("StandardOutput", standardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    retDirects.Add("StandardError", standardError.ReadToEnd());
                }
                catch { }


            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    p.Kill();
                    p.CloseMainWindow();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        return retDirects;
    }
```

Comment: As I recall you can pass a delegate in as part of the StartInfo that will be "CalledBack" as new data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Process.BeginOutputReadLine` to initiate the firing of the `Process.OutputDataRecieved` event. `UseShellExecute` must be `false` and `Redirect<StreamOfChoice>Output` must be true, as in your example code.

There is an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) which I won't regurgitate here. I've noticed that some programs use the different streams for what I thought were unexpected purposes so it may be appropriate to use the same handler for events from the different streams.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "ReadToEnd", use "Read" of a few bytes (even one byte at time) in a loop. Read will block until it reads the number of bytes you specified. Find the correct number of bytes, and you should be able to read the strings from the standard output.